# NgStyle with dynamic content proper syntax angular 4/2

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ng-style

I am using NgStyle to dynamically set the background image of a container in angular 4.

This site: Says the proper syntax is the following

```
[ngStyle]="{'background-image': venueobject.groupphoto[0]}">
```

or

```
[ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'venueobject.groupphoto[0]'}">
```

I also saw turning the whole thing into a string:

```
[ngStyle]="'background-image': 'url(' + 'venueobject.groupphoto[0]'+ ')'">
```

and

```
[ngStyle]="'background-image: url(' + venueobject.groupphoto[0] + ')'">
```

but I keep not getting it. The page is rendering so my html is not broken, but the image is not showing.

This is currently not yay and I am trying to make it yay.

Please help me make it yay

Hugs and kisses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following:

In your ts file:

```
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }

getBackgroundImg() {
    // replace the path to your image here
    const img = 'assets/img/wall.png';
    const style = `background-image: url(${img})`;
    // this is to bypass this warning 'WARNING: sanitizing unsafe style value background-image: url(assets/img/wall.png) (see http://g.co/ng/security#xss)'
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(style);
}
```

In your html file:

```
<div [style]="getBackgroundImg()"></div>
```

You will also need to set the width and height of the div to see the image.